# On item Click Listener of Recycler view to show Image

Tags: android, android-imageview

I got images from my server in a list using `RecyclerView`. When I click on one of the items in `RecyclerView`, I want the image in that item to open a new activity. How can I get that image? Thanks in Advance.

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter, Context context) {

        super();
        this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v,context,getDataAdapter);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Viewholder, int position) {

        GetDataAdapter getDataAdapter1 = getDataAdapter.get(position);

        imageLoader1 = ServerImageParseAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

        imageLoader1.get(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(),
                ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                        Viewholder.networkImageView,//Server Image
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,//Before loading server image the default showing image.
                        android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert //Error image if requested image dose not found on server.
                )
        );


      Viewholder.networkImageView.setImageUrl(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(), imageLoader1);
        Viewholder.ImageTitleNameView.setText(getDataAdapter1.getImageTitleName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return getDataAdapter.size();
    }

  //  public static
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

      public TextView ImageTitleNameView;
     public NetworkImageView networkImageView;

    List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter ;//= new List<GetDataAdapter>();
        Context context;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView,Context context,List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter) {

            super(itemView);
            this.getDataAdapter=getDataAdapter;
            this.context=context;
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            ImageTitleNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item);

           // networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VollyNetworkImageView1);
            networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VollyNetworkImageView1);

        }
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            GetDataAdapter getDataAdapters=this.getDataAdapter.get(position);
            Intent intent=new Intent(this.context,SecondPage.class);
            intent.putExtra("image_title",getDataAdapters.getImageTitleName());
            intent.putExtra("image_url",getDataAdapters.getImageServerUrl());
            this.context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
}
```

**SecondPage.java**

```
 imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imge);

    Intent i = getIntent();

      int resid =i.getIntExtra("image_url", 0);

     imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt("image_url"+getIntent().getStringExtra("image_url")));

    imageView.setImageResource(resid);
```

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your images are stored in an ArrayList, pass the position of the RecyclerView element via intent and set the `src` of the ImageView in your `SecondPage.java` as:

**`OnClick`:**

```
myIntent.putExtra("imageIndex", position);
```

**SecondPage.java**

```
imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imge);

Intent i = getIntent();

int imgIndex = i.getIntExtra("imageIndex", 0);

imageView.setImageResource(ArrayList.get(imgIndex));
```

In case, you are passing an ImageUrl via intent use Picasso to diaplay an image in ImageView as:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Make sure you add the Picasso library to your project gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: Thank you suhayl, but it does not work for me , any other suggestion.

Comment: whats the error you are getting? Also can you paste the GetDataAdapter class with your question?

Comment: public class GetDataAdapter {

    public String ImageServerUrl;
    public String ImageTitleName;

    public String getImageServerUrl() {
        return ImageServerUrl;
    }

    public void setImageServerUrl(String imageServerUrl) {
        this.ImageServerUrl = imageServerUrl;
    }

    public String getImageTitleName() {
        return ImageTitleName;
    }

    public void setImageTitleNamee(String Imagetitlename) {
        this.ImageTitleName = Imagetitlename;
    }

}

Comment: The problem is I didn't get the image from my server.

Comment: So you are using the url of the images?

Comment: In case so pass the url as a string in the intent and use Picasso library to display the Image in an ImageView using url.
See my updated answer

Comment: ya. i got text field values but i didn't get the image.Ok, let me try.

Comment: See my updated answer. And do mark the answer correct if it helped. Thanks !

Comment: Did you try this:
Picasso.with(SecondPage.this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);

Comment: Did you change the context to SecondPage.this or getContext(0 or getActivity() ?

Comment: Thanks ray.. I got the image